# Using BlazeDS with jsf, jsp frontend

Tags: jsp, jsf, blazeds, javabeans, frontend

i wonder if i could set up a jsf bean that is capable of connecting to the BlazeDS Application within a tomcat server. My problem is that i have already a flex application and i want to reuse the same data access classes which i wrote for the flex application with another frontend than flex. Can someone think of a way to realize that?

Thank you

EDIT: Or is it possible to share the class implementations for the blazeDS Server as a jar include through 2 differnt projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to invoke blazeds endpoints from java, if that's what you want (take a look [here](http://cornelcreanga.com/2008/10/connecting-java-applications-with-blaze-ds/). However reading your post I have the impression that some of your code is tightly coupled...you should be able to reuse your services (they can be designed in such a way to not depend on blazeds concepts like flexcontext etc).

Comment: Indeed i have some business methods to use but i need to insure that several reentant locks stay alive. That is why i want to access the same tomcat app for that since tomcat is an application on the server. But how about sharing the same bean component between blazeds and a jsf webapp.